# Online resize of mounted ext3 logical volume

Tags: linux, lvm, sles10

I am on SLES10 and am trying to extend the size of /usr I did:

```
lvextend -L +5G /dev/vg00/vol03
```

which seemed to work. Now when I try to do:

```
resize2fs /dev/vg00/vol03 11G
```

I get:

```
an ... is mounted; can't resize a mounted filesystem
```

I also tried:

```
ext2online /dev/vg00/vol03 11G
```

which results in:

```
warning - device size 157...., specified 288.... error invalid argument: seeking to 11811155968
```

The host is an VMWARE SLES9 so I can't boot from CD and therefore can not unmount /usr

Please Help.

Comment: Please spend a few more seconds formatting your question. The easier you make it for people to read and understand the question, the more likely it will be answered quickly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't specify the size of the new partition when you run ext2online, just let it run and auto-detect.

You've probably specified a size that's slightly larger than the actual LV.

Answer (score 1):

Grab a linux boot CD like the [Gparted live CD](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php) iso or the [ubuntu desktop distro](http://www.ubuntu.com/) iso and resize your volume from there.  You can mount the iso in the virtual cd-rom drive for your virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

What happens with:

```
ext2online /dev/vg00/vol03
```

Comment: I am such a noob - I followed this thread http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?t=29143 last post - and now I got lost 5 GB somewhere. I Resized /home from 10GB to 5GB and now I can not increase my /usr where could the 5 GB be???

Comment: tried again to reduce size of tmp now - did run ext2online /dev/vg00/vol04 now and again i get the same error as above:
error : Ivalid argument: seeking to 6222...